# Add image in pdf using Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

I've a problem for adding images into a PDF using Prawn as pdf generator. I'm trying to add image using the following code:

```
def header
  text "something"
  image "#{Prawn::DATADIR}/images/logo_small.png"
end
```

But app replies to me with the following error:

```
 uninitialized constant Prawn::DATADIR
```

Where is the mistake?

P.S. My app is running on Rails 3.1 & Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`Prawn::DATADIR` is new, it has been introduced recently about 2 or 3 months ago. Previously one would have used `Prawn::BASEDIR/data` instead. If you are using the current `0.12.0` version of the gem, you should stick with `Prawn::BASEDIR/data`. If you are using Rails 3.1, you can also put your image in the asset directory and use
`"#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo_small.png"`