# Prawn pdf 2 and Rmagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick, prawn

i've got trouble for croping a picture with Rmagick and then display with Prawn

Here is the code :

First a method to instantiate the image with RMagick :

```
def build_magick_image(path)
    if path.instance_of?(StringIO)
      Magick::Image.from_blob(path.read)
    else
      Magick::Image.read(path)
    end.first
end
```

In my case i have an instance of StringIO.
Then i crop the picture :

```
img = build_magick_image(picture_path)
cropped_img = img.resize_to_fill(1735, 1560)
```

But now i can't find how to display it in my Prawn pdf.
My last try is :

```
pdf.image cropped_img, at: [image_x, image_y], height: image_height.mm , width: inner_page_width.mm
```

But obviously it doesn't work.

Can someone help me?

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try with wicked PDF, one of my colleagues created a pdf with an image in it in this way, hope this helps you.
 `pdf-reports-body table td div.acknowledged_status_true {
  background-image: url('<%= asset_data_base64("acknowledge/acknowledged_status_true.png") %>');
}
`

Comment: Unfortunately, i work on an  existing feature that has been developed with Prawn, so i can't change to wicked

Comment: ok, Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565412/add-image-in-pdf-using-prawn) out, I guess you must have check it.

Comment: I checked it out, but thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

I found your question when I was trying to figure out the same thing  Here's the solution I came up with:

Wrap your image blob in a `StringIO` object, which will give Prawn the interface it needs. In your specific case:

```
cropped_img_sio = StringIO.open(cropped_img.to_blob)
pdf.image cropped_img_sio, at: [image_x, image_y], height: image_height.mm, width: inner_page_width.mm
```